# Preparing for Rosh Hashana during Elul

Tags: rosh-hashanah-new-year, how-to, elul

I hear often about the need for preparing for Rosh Hashana during Elul. Can anyone offer some practical suggestions as to what primarily this preparation entails. Sourced answers, only, please.

Comment: Learn halachot about rosh hashana.

Comment: What DoubleAA said plus I would recommend learning Hilchot Teshuva from the Rambam or Sefarim like Shaare Teshuba.

Comment: Related but not duplicate: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/45252/5323