# Sefarim to learn in Elul

Tags: product-recommendation, torah-study, jewish-books, elul, months

Which sefarim are traditionally learned in Elul*, because they have a special significance to the mood and message of the month?

---

*<sub>Or even without a tradition, which sefarim are good to learn during this time?</sub>

Comment: I [answered my own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), but would still like to see what other people have to say!

Comment: See [*The Power of Teshuvah*](http://www.artscroll.com/Products/POTP.html), [*Praying with Fire*](http://www.artscroll.com/Products/PPWFP.html), [*Praying with Fire 2*](http://www.artscroll.com/Products/PWF2P.html), and [*The Practical Guide to Teshuvah*](http://www.judaicapress.com/The-Practical-Guide-to-Teshuvah.html)

Comment: See [Wisdom in the Hebrew Months] (http://www.amazon.com/dp/1422608980/?tag=mh0b-20&hvadid=3481288179&ref=pd_sl_1xsuvuxocr_e) and Wisdom in the Hebrew Months volume 2 (http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1422614662/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_dp_ss_1?pf_rd_p=1535523722&pf_rd_s=lpo-top-stripe-1&pf_rd_t=201&pf_rd_i=1422608980&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_r=1T14VKMNXMPTVVV5P8PB)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<s>I forget who told me this, but I heard that Tomer Devorah is traditionally studied in the month of Elul.</s>

I've [been told](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/45252/sefarim-to-learn-in-elul/45253?noredirect=1#comment119976_45253) that the Bobover Rebbe told his chassidim to learn Tomer Devorah this year, and that Rav Moshe Wolfson told his Kehilla the same a few years back.

This practice makes sense, because the first chapter of Tomer Devorah is about Hashem's 13 Middos, and how they should be taken into practice, which is a focus of the month of Elul and Yamim Noraim.

([Hebrewbooks](http://hebrewbooks.org/51319), [print Hebrew](http://zbermanbooks.com/product-43036.html), [print English](http://zbermanbooks.com/tomer-devorah-palm-tree-of-deborah-hc.html))
<sub>These are just examples, but you can find more of all the above types at Hebrewbooks and other seforim websites; I linked to them for illustrative purposes only, not necessarily because they are the best of each type.</sub>

Comment: I did that one Elul for mussar seder!

Comment: @YEZ This is what I'm learning this year Elul....on the right path, will meet people ;)

Comment: If you think Tomer Devorah is about the 13 middot, you haven't made it past the first chapter.

Comment: @Chanoch ( _Just started the second perek_ )

Comment: @Chanoch maybe you want to start a chaburah ?

Comment: BTW the Bobover Rebbe (RMD Unger shlita) asked his Chassidim this year to learn TD as a preparation for Ellul. A few years ago Rav Moshe Wolfson asked his Kehila the same and one one his Chassidim (R. Beryl Fink) put out an addition broken up into 30 parts so you can finish it once a month.

Comment: I saw in a sefer that the the 13 middos said by Hashem (parshas VaYeChal) correspond to the *Guf* while the 13 middos said by Yona correspond to the *nefesh*. When I saw that I thought perhaps that is the reason why people learn TD during Ellul.

Comment: @eramm See most recent edit, regarding your second comment; thanks!!

Comment: @eramm I don't understand your third comment.

Answer (score 7):

Rabbi Yosef Ber Soleveitchik would [teach Likkutei Torah](http://crownheights.info/jewish-news/30873/ou-ceo-remembers-the-ravs-class-on-lekutei-torah/) from the Ba'al HaTanya during Elul in preparation for Rosh Hashana.

The relevant Ma'amarim start in [Parshas Reih](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/lkutey/29/32a.htm) and continue from there.

I haven't been able to find someone who reports specifically what from there he would learn with his students.

Comment: I would guess that over the years he did different pieces of each parsha's likkutei torah, just like he did the rest of the year.

Comment: @Yitzchak, he learned Likkutei Torah through the whole year? Publicly?

Comment: this is the way I heard it: he used to give a shiur  in his shul in Boston, and like many rabbanim would end with a vort on the parsha on Thursdays. These were always taken from Likutei Torah, and in Elul he would extend it to fill a large portion of the shiur.

Answer (score 7):

I know many Yeshivas where the Rosh Yeshiva interrupts his regularly scheduled programming of a vaad or whatever public mussar seder he has to go through Shaarei Teshuva of Rabbeinu Yona during Elul.  I know the Rosh Yeshiva of Passaic (R' Meir Stern) used to do this for his machshava chabura, but I don't know if he still does.

In Ner Israel, the Rosh Yeshiva (during my time there) would do this for 5 minutes after Maariv for Elul.

Comment: I don't know if Rav Meir Stern does that anymore http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/47498/5323

Answer (score 7):

Shulchan Aruch HaRav writes ([O.C. 429](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh3/1/429/index.htm)):

> חכמים הראשונים תקנו בזמן שבית המקדש היה קיים שיתחילו הדרשנים לדרוש ברבים הלכות הרגל שלשים יום לפני הרגל דהיינו ... ומי"ד באלול ואילך ידרשו הלכות החג ... ותקנה זו לא נתבטלה מישראל  אף לאחר שחרב בית המקדש ... והעיקר לדרוש ולהורות להם דרכי ה' וללמד להם המעשה אשר יעשון ולא כמו שנוהגין עכשיו
>   ובדורות הללו שאין החכם שונה לתלמידיו הלכות (לפי שהכל כתוב בספר) מצוה על כל אחד ואחד שילמוד הלכות הרגל קודם הרגל עד שיהיה בקי בהם וידע המעשה אשר יעשה

Summary: Starting from the 14th of Elul one needs to learn Hilchos Sukkos from Halacha books until one is thoroughly familiar with them enough to know the proper procedure for the holiday.

Comment: Does this have "special significance to the mood and message of the month"?

Comment: @YEZ, I think that if Halacha requires learning something for the majority of the month, that topic has inherent significance for the month. But for a specific connection the presumed "mood and message" being preparation for the Yom HaDin, I could think of a few options.

Answer (score 4):

One year in high school, my rebbi taught our class [Hilchos Teshuva](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=1&hilchos=5&hilite=) from the Rambam during the month of Elul.

Answer (score 2):

I am learning Nesiv HaTeshuva, by the Maharal.  Nesivos Olam is the Maharal's "mussar sefer" according to his introduction, and Nesiv HaTeshuva is the section about teshuva.  It talks about the nature of Teshuva, and is therefore helpful in appreciating the significance of Teshuva.

Comment: +1 this is the sefer I chose this year as well. It's not easy to go through even with the machon yerushalayim edition. Would love to hear shiurim based on this chapter.

Comment: @eramm I've actually incorporated it several times now into a shiur that I give.  But some of it is very esoteric, and some relies on accepting internal consistencies in the Maharal.  I generally find that the Mechon Yerushalayim edition makes things harder, but I think the same about Oz V'Hadar gemaras and Mossad HaRav Kook Rishonim - I guess it's a matter of taste.  I use the Feldheim.

Comment: Put the shiurim on line so we can all partake.

Answer (score 2):

**Chovos HaLevovos** – Rabbeinu Bachya ibn Paquda (Early 11th Century). Arguably the most important mussar work of all time, the Chovos HaLevovos is divided into ten Shearim (“Gates”).

For Ellul perhapes

**Shaar HaTeshuva** (“Gate of Repentance”) – on repentance.

**Shaar Cheshbon HaNefesh** (“Gate of Self-Accounting”) – on the importance of introspection and self-examination and the proper ways to do this.

Would be the most relevent.

Answer (score 1):

Reb Meir Stern gives a weekly Rambam shiur. During Elul Zman he learns the Rambam on Teshuvah.

Comment: No prob. Just want to note that he gives a lumdish shuir and blends in the lumdis a lot of Mussar.

Comment: Interesting. Never been to Rav Stern's shiur, but I could probably ask a friend. Does he let people record the lectures?

Comment: Watch your keyboard! ;) ....once I was in there fixing your typos, I also fixed a coupla spelling errors, hope you don't mind. If you do (though I don't see why you would), you can always fix that by [edit]ing your answer again.

Comment: Also, you might consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: No he's makpid about recording the Yeshiva shiurim.

Comment: Ah. Oh well....

Comment: It's on Shabbos either way. But there's a chozer on Motzei Shabbos. The RY allows the recording of the chozer.

Comment: That might be useful....does he allow people outside yeshiva to listen to them also?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18014/discussion-between-david-and-shokhet).